# How to pass array of object pointers to function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, pointers

I am having trouble passing an *array of object pointer*s from `main()` to a function from different class.

I created an array of object pointers `listP`in `main()` and I want to modify the array with a function `editProduct` in class `Manager` such as adding new or edit object.

Furthermore, I want to pass the whole `listP` array instead of `listP[index]`. How to achieve this or is there any better way? Sorry, I am very new to c++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Product 
{
protected:
    string id, name;
    float price;

public:
    Product() 
    {
        id = "";
        name = "";
        price = 0;
    }

    Product(string _id, string _name, float _price)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
        price = _price;
    }
};

class Manager 
{
protected:
    string id, pass;

public:
    Manager(string _id, string _pass)
    {
        id = _id;
        pass = _pass;
    }

    string getId() const {  return id;  }
    string getPass() const {   return pass;  }

    void editProduct(/*array of listP*/ )
    {
        //i can edit array of listP here without copying 
    }
};

int main()
{
    int numProduct = 5;
    int numManager = 2;
    Product* listP[numProduct];
    Manager* listM[numManager] = { new Manager("1","alex"), new Manager("2", "Felix") };
    bool exist = false;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numProduct; i++) { //initialize to default value
        listP[i] = new Product();
    }
    string ID, PASS;
    cin >> ID;
    cin >> PASS;

    for (int i = 0; i < numManager; i++) 
    {
        if (listM[i]->getId() == ID && listM[i]->getPass() == PASS) {
            exist = true;
            index = i;
        }
    }

    if (exist == true) 
        listM[index]->editProduct(/*array of listP */);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all don't "using namespace std", see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `listP` is a pointer to an array of `Product`, you have the following two option to pass it to the function.

1. The `editProduct` can be changed to accept the pointer to an array of size `N`, where `N` is the size of the passed pointer to the array, which is known at compile time:

   ```
   template<std::size_t N>
   void editProduct(Product* (&listP)[N])
   {
        // Now the listP can be edited, here without copying 
   }
   ```
2. or it must accept a pointer to an object, so that it can refer the array

   ```
   void editProduct(Product** listP)
   {
       // find the array size for iterating through the elements
   }
   ```

In above both cases, you will call the function as

```
listM[index]->editProduct(listP);
```

---

That been said, your code has a few issues.

- First, the array sizes `numProduct` and `numManager` must be compiled time constants, so that you don't end up creating a non-standard variable length array.
- Memory leak at the end of `main` as you have not `delete`d what you have `new`ed.
- Also be aware [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- You could have simply used [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) depending on where the object should be allocated in memory. By which, you would have avoided all these issues of memory leak as well as pointer syntaxes.

For example, using `std::vector`, you could do simply

```
#include <vector> 

// in Manager class
void editProduct(std::vector<Product>& listP)
{
    // listP.size() for size of the array.
    // pass by reference and edit the  listP!
}
```

in `main()`

```
// 5 Product objects, and initialize to default value
std::vector<Product> listP(5);
std::vector<Manager> listM{ {"1","alex"}, {"2", "Felix"} };

// ... other codes
for (const Manager& mgr : listM)
{
    if (mgr.getId() == ID && mgr.getPass() == PASS)
    {
        // ... code
    }
}

if (exist == true) {
    listM[index]->editProduct(listP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have arrays as parameters in C++, you can only have pointers. Since your array is an array of pointers you can use a double pointer to access the array.

```
void editProduct(Product** listP){
```

and

```
listM[index]->editProduct(listP);
```

Of course none of these arrays of pointers are necessary. You could simplify your code a lot if you just used regular arrays.

```
Product listP[numProduct];
Manager listM[numManager] = { Manager("1","alex"), Manager("2", "Felix")};

...

for(int i = 0; i < numManager; i++ ){
    if(listM[i].getId() == ID  && listM[i].getPass() == PASS) {
    exist = true;
    index = i;
    }
}

if(exist == true){
    listM[index].editProduct(listP);
}
```